# Understanding namespaces in Ruby

Tags: ruby

In the code below:

```
::Trace.tracer = ::Trace::ZipkinTracer.new()
```

what is the relation between `Trace` and `ZipkinTracer`?

Comment: Are you asking about what `ZipkinTracer` does, or about the syntax? If it's about the syntax, then you are merely instantiating the class `Trace::ZipkinTracer` with `#new` constructor and no arguments. The leading `::` before `Trace` module name serve to establish the "root", just like `/usr/lib/something` in the filesystem has leading `/` to establish the root.

Comment: @BorisStitnicky today I learned about the "root" syntax. Maybe this should an answer?

Comment: I also realized this was too long for comments. Since @MarekLipka just now edited the answer with leading `::` explanation, I provide just the LHS explanation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`ZipkinTracer` is inside of `Trace` namespace, like this:

```
module Trace
  class ZipkinTracer
  # ...
  end
end
```

The `::` before constant name means that you point to the root. For example in the following code:

```
class Class1
end

module Module1
  class Class1
  end

  def foo
    ::Class1
  end
end
```

`::Class1` ensures that you refer to the "root" `Class1`. If you had:

```
def foo
  Class1
end
```

the `Module1::Class1` would be referred.

Answer (score 3):

This code does the following thing. First, it instantiates class `ZipkinTracer`:

```
new_instance = Trace::ZipkinTracer.new()
```

Then, it calls `#tracer=` method of the `Trace` module:

```
Trace.tracer=( new_instance )
```

Ruby syntax allows this to be rewritten as

```
Trace.tracer = new_instance
```

In this case, no assignment is happening, but a method ending in `=` is called. Methods ending in `=` are allowed in Ruby, used generally for attribute assignment, and they are special in that they always return the *assigned value* (that is, their argument), regardless of what other return value you might be trying to prescribe:

```
class Foo
  def bar=( value )
    puts "Method #bar= called!"
    @bar = value
    puts "Trying to return Quux!"
    return "Quux!"
  end

  def bar; @bar end
end

foo = Foo.new
foo.bar #=> nil
foo.bar = "Baz!"
#=> Method #bar= called!
#=> Trying to return Quux!
#=> "Baz!" -- attempt to explicitly return "Quux!" failed
foo.bar #=> "Baz!"
```