# What does constant prefixed with double colons mean?

Tags: ruby

I have seen some `constants` prefixed with double colons like

`::DATE_FORMAT`

What does this mean, and how are they different from the normal `constants` ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17362545/understanding-namespaces-in-ruby/17362617#17362617

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the scope resolution operator. With an empty LHS, it is scoping to global.

It would be used when simply accessing the property/method/etc by its name alone would be ambiguous, e.g. a `DATE_FORMAT` available in scope which isn't the one you're after.